# How to add GPS latitude and longitude using Exiftool in mac (how to edit meta data in jpeg)

Tags: r, gps, jpeg, exif, exiftool

I have a bunch jpeg image that is obtained from FLIR camera. Along with that images I collected the GPS coordinates also. Now I'm trying to take the GPS latitude and longitude to the metadata of the image.

I wrote a program in R programming language to find the GPS location of each image with respect to the time(when ever the GPS location time and the camera time matches, I took that coordinates).

ie, for a particular image, I have GPSLatitude <- 19.33423 and GPSLongitude <- 72.090834

But now I need to add those exact GPS location to the image.

I tried to do that with Exiftool. I'm using Mac osX sierra. In that I installed exiftool. But now I don't know the how to update GPS data using that.

Can anyone help me. If possible let me know the method to update the data directly from the R programming language itself

Thanks

Comment: Additional info for anyone else, [here's](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php/topic,8029.0.html) the OPs thead on the Exiftool forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Result from the [thread](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php/topic,8029.0.html) on the exiftool forum

`output <- system(sprintf("exiftool -GPSLatitude=%f -GPSLongitude=%f %s",q,p,aa))`
or
`output <- system(paste("exiftool -GPSLatitude=",q," -GPSLongitude=",p," ", aa))`

Answer (score 8):

To add the gps coordinates with exiftool:

```
exiftool -XMP:GPSLongitude="-84.683333"  -XMP:GPSLatitude="10.502117"  -GPSLongitudeRef="West" -GPSLatitudeRef="North" photo.jpg
```

The values are just floating point numbers as got from Google Maps for example.

Comment: This did not work for me on exiftool 10.10.

exiftool said it updated the file, but it just changed the modified time.

Comment: Why `-XMP:GPS...` instead of `-EXIF:GPS...`?

Comment: It would be more portable to use `-EXIF:GPS` version, not all programs support `-XMP:GPS` version

Answer (score 2):

In order to deal with latitude and longitude possible negative values, I suggest to first import in XMP, then copy from XMP to EXIF :
(bash code)

```
exiftool -XMP:GPSLatitude="$latitude" -XMP:GPSLongitude="$longitude"  "$image"
exiftool "-gps:all<xmp-exif:all" "-gps:all<composite:all" "-gpsdatestamp<gpsdatetime" "-gpstimestamp<gpsdatetime" "$image"
exiftool -EXIF:GPSAltitude="$altitude" -EXIF:GPSAltitudeRef#="0" -EXIF:GPSMapDatum='WGS-84' "$image"
```

- copy xmp->exif https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=2257.0
- delete gps tags https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=4686.0

Answer (score 1):

When trying to do a similar thing as suggested by [Casto Salobreña](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7217328/casto-salobre%C3%B1a) i got the following error:

```
$ exiftool -XMP:GPSLatitude=1.2843265 -XMP:GPSLongitude=36.8798949 -GPSLatitudeRef=South -GPSLongitudeRef=East -P test.jpeg 
Warning: Truncated PreviewIFD directory. IFD dropped. - test.jpeg
Error: [minor] Bad PreviewIFD directory - test.jpeg
    0 image files updated
    1 files weren't updated due to errors
```

to fix this i have dropped the `Ref` options removing and by changing the `South` direction (or potentially would need to do the same for `West`) to a negative number:

```
$ exiftool -XMP:GPSLatitude=-1.2843265 -XMP:GPSLongitude=36.8798949 -P test.jpeg 
    1 image files updated
```

now i test:

```
$ exiftool -l test.jpeg
...
GPS Position
    1 deg 17' 3.58" S, 36 deg 52' 47.62" E
...
```