# Write exif data back to jpeg in R

Tags: r, metadata, jpeg

All,

I am using R and exifr to read in a jpeg with a ton of exif data entries (~150 different tags). I use a bunch of those to convert/change the values in the jpeg. After that, I would like to save the new values (in matrix form now) with the same exif data back to a jpeg. So, ideally, I would have two jpegs with different values, but everything else is the same. Is there a way to use exifr to write exif data back to a file? That is, read in a jpeg, manipulate it, and then save it back as jpeg with the exact same metadata?

I have thought about different approaches, but haven't really gotten far in either.
Maybe using the raster package and then exporting it as a geoTIFF, but that would obviously mean a change in file format.
The jpeg package loses the metadata while reading in the image.

Thanks y'all!

PS: There is a similar question about writing metadata, but it's almost 2 years old and only refers to GPS tags.

Comment: I see a couple ([link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41849691/how-to-add-gps-latitude-and-longitude-using-exiftool-in-mac-how-to-edit-meta-da/) [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47293978/r-write-exif-data-to-jpeg-file)) of previous questions which call exiftool.  If you went that route, then the process isn't significantly different.  A quick google search pulled up [exiv](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/exiv), but that appears to be limited to EXIF data, not IPTC/XMP.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I had seen those before, but was wondering if there is a quicker way than explicitly stating what tags to write. I have almost 150 exif data tags, I'd prefer not to have to write them out. Hence my hope to do it with exifr, which calls exiftool. But I guess I'd only have to do it once...